# Using Apache HTTP Components (client) and the examples given just won't work

Tags: java, apache, http, servlets, httpclient

I have tried using the quick given example of:

```
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://localhost/");
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    if (entity != null) {
        InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
        try {
            // do something useful
        } finally {
    instream.close();
        }
    }
```

[Found here](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/fundamentals.html).

But I copy and paste this code across and it throws a few errors.

1. The line:

   ```
   HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
   ```

   Throws an error saying that I should change the Default Http Client to a HttpClient. How can I stop this error? You can't cast it, that throws another error but on runtime, whereas the original isn't.
2. The line:

   ```
   HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
   ```

   Eclipse claims this line should be changed to *'executeMethod()'*, again this can be cast but throws a runtime exception, I have never been able to use the *'execute'* at all since using HTTP components, and it's always thrown this error.

Am I missing imports?

Also, if you have any information on how to stream data to and from a server/client, that would be great!

Thanks,

Sam

Comment: What versions of httpclient and httpcore are you using?  I tried this with both 4.0 and 4.2.1 and after adding a try/catch and sending Throwables to the console, I get the following output each time: "Connection to http://localhost refused".  Are you using a regular Java project in Eclipse to run this test?  I used an Indigo Eclipse version and Java 6 for my tests.

Comment: Show your imports. It looks like you are somehow mixing HTTP client 3.x and 4.x.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/3375990/8753 which links to full samples with the proper imports.

Comment: Of course. We are currently using HTTP client 3. And I'm assuming some of this code refers to 4. Which is annoying. I don't think we can use 4. I'll look into it and get another comment back to you guys.

Comment: Yeah it's HTTP client 3.x, I think 3.1. I can't import anything higher than this, otherwise all servers would require modification. 

Also, I've been looking for days, but can't find a decent HTTP client 3 example which sends streams of data. But not only sends streams of data, how does a java servlet pick up on the streamed data?